# How to use Intersection (AND) trait filter with xunit.runner.console

Tags: testing, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I've categorized my test with two principal traits (Severity and Domain) and I need to execute them filtering by the intersection of both of them.

With dotnet test it's possible to do it without problem, but I need to do it with the xunit.runner.console (.exe) because the tests are running in a pipeline that uses a Xunit Builder.
I've only managed to run an 'OR' filter with the xunit runner console.

This is an example of how I run an intersection filter with dotnet test:

```
dotnet test --filter "Domain=User&Severity=Critical"
```

With the previous command I run the test that have both traits.

On the other hand, with xunit runner console the only similar thing I've read online is something like this:

```
xunit.console.exe MyTestPackage.dll -trait "Domain=User" -trait "Severity=Critical"
```

The problem is the execution is not the same, but it results on an 'OR' filter, I mean, that are executed the tests with the first trait or with the second trait.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)); `xunit.console` is deprecated - its highly recommended to stop using it.